# How to create custom UITextView with placeholder objective c .?

Tags: objective-c

Step 1:-
         Create a class with sub Class UITextView and put the name of      class KDPlaceHolderTextView

copy and paste the code in KDPlaceHolderTextView.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>   
   IB_DESIGNABLE 

@interface KDPlaceHolderTextView : UITextView  

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBInspectable NSString *placeholder;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBInspectable UIColor *placeholderColor;  

/*!
 This method is used to set the UITextView Notification and UitextField   begin nitification to set the placeholder text  
 @param  NSNotification to be a notification  
 @return void  
 */
-(void)textChanged:(NSNotification*)notification;  

@end
```

Step 2:-

Add the this code in KDPlaceHolderTextView.m file

```
  #import "KDPlaceHolderTextView.h"  
  @interface KDPlaceHolderTextView ()  

  @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *placeHolderLabel;  

@end  

@implementation KDPlaceHolderTextView  

CGFloat const UI_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT_CHANGED_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.25;  

- (void)dealloc  
{  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];  
}  

- (void)awakeFromNib  
{
    [super awakeFromNib];  

    // Use Interface Builder User Defined Runtime Attributes to set  
    // placeholder and placeholderColor in Interface Builder.  
    if (!self.placeholder) {  
        [self setPlaceholder:@""];  
    }  

    if (!self.placeholderColor) {  
        [self setPlaceholderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];  
    }  

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self   selector:@selector(textChanged:) name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification   object:nil];  
}  

/*!  
 This method is used to set the frame Placeholder lable  
 @param  CGrect frame to be a frame  
 @return id  
 */  
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  
{
    if( (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) )
    {  
        [self setPlaceholder:@""];  
        [self setPlaceholderColor:[UI Color lightGrayColor]];  
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self   selector:@selector(textChanged:) name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification   object:nil];  
    }  
    return self;  
}  

- (void)textChanged:(NSNotification *)notification  
{
    if([[self placeholder] length] == 0)  
    {  
        return;  
    }  

    [UIView   animateWithDuration:UI_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT_CHANGED_ANIMATION_DURATION  animations:^{  
        if([[self text] length] == 0)  
        {
            [[self viewWithTag:999] setAlpha:1];  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            [[self viewWithTag:999] setAlpha:0];  
        }  
    }];  
}  

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {  
    [super setText:text];  
    [self textChanged:nil];  
}  

/*!  
 This method is used to draw the rect in placeholder lable acording to   amount of text  
 @param  CGrect to be a rect  
 @return void  
 */  
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  
{
    if( [[self placeholder] length] > 0 )  
    {  
        if (_placeHolderLabel == nil )  
        {  
            _placeHolderLabel = [[UILabel alloc]   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,8,self.bounds.size.width - 16,0)];  
            _placeHolderLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;  
            _placeHolderLabel.numberOfLines = 0;  
            _placeHolderLabel.font = self.font;  
            _placeHolderLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
            _placeHolderLabel.textColor = self.placeholderColor;  
            _placeHolderLabel.alpha = 0;  
            _placeHolderLabel.tag = 999;  
            [self addSubview:_placeHolderLabel];  
        }  

        _placeHolderLabel.text = self.placeholder;  
        [_placeHolderLabel sizeToFit];  
        [self sendSubviewToBack:_placeHolderLabel];  
    }  

    if( [[self text] length] == 0 && [[self placeholder] length] > 0 )  
    {  
        [[self viewWithTag:999] setAlpha:1];  
    }   

    [super drawRect:rect];  
}  
@end
```

Step 3:-
 Go to storyboard file and drag the UITexview in viewcotroller and assign the class KDPlaceHolderTextView

and see the attribute inspector set the PlaceHolder text or color

finally build and run the project

Answer (score 0):

Check this in [GitHub](https://github.com/gcamp/GCPlaceholderTextView)

You just have to change class name to (GCPlaceholderTextView) in UITextView interface.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly possible to add a Placeholder in textView But we can make use of UILabel to do the same.

Take a property of UILabel

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)  UILabel *placeholederLabel;
```

Then in YourViewDidLoad.

```
placeholederLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0,textView.frame.size.width - 30.0, 40.0)];


[placeholederLabel setText:@"Enter Your text here."];
[placeholederLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[placeholederLabel setTextColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

[textView addSubview:placeholederLabel];
```

And then write textView delegate Methods

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)theTextView
{
     if (![textView hasText]) {
     placeholederLabel.hidden = NO;
}
}

- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(![textView hasText]) {
      placeholederLabel.hidden = NO;
}
else{
    placeholederLabel.hidden = YES;
 }  
}
```